# Installing a maven project with a dependency on a parent

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have a collection of related projects that inherit from a common maven project.
Since they are still in alpha release, they all (including the parent) are deployed in the Sonatype snapshots repository, instead of Maven central.

The configuration for accessing the maven central is in the parent project of my application.
So its POM specifies as its parent:

```
...
<parent>
  <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
  <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
  <version>7</version>
</parent>
...
```

And set the corresponding repository at Sonatype:

```
...
<repositories>
    <repository>
    <id>snapshots-repo</id>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    <releases>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>
...
```

So the children projects do not have to repeat this configuration.
The parent also provides many other things that are common to all my projects.
Currently I keep all these projects in unrelated directories.

Now, if a user of my application checkout one of my projects and attempt to install it with `mvn install`, he will receive the error: `Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact ...`

This makes sense to me, since the project cannot access the Sonatype repository (e.g., for downloading the parent) since it is precisely the parent the one that contains how to connect to such repository.

I do not want to request the user to install first the parent project, since he should be able to install what he needs in just one single step.

Then what is the recommended way to distribute my libraries so the user can install any of them with one single command ?

It occurs to me that I could include the parent POM in each of the projects (for example, using git submodules) so the parent can be resolved locally. But I am wondering if this is the best way to organize this (?). Any better alternative is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I added this to my  ~/.m2/settings.xml so the parent POM could be resolved in the Sonatype snapshots repository. Apparently it is working fine and the parent POM is resolved as any other dependency.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
     <id>allow-snapshots</id>
        <activation><activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault></activation>
     <repositories>
       <repository>
         <id>snapshots-repo</id>
         <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
         <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
         <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
       </repository>
     </repositories>
   </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Start using a repository manager which makes your life easier and you should prevent defining repositories in your pom files.

Comment: which one do you suggest ?

Comment: Artifactory and Nexus are both decent, try the public demos to see which one you prefer.

Comment: so with those repositories user of my libraries do not have to configure snapshot repositories as in the one I am using ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it to one step install than you have to list enough information in the project pom, i.e. either:

- no parent pom, put all the information into each project pom
- tell maven where to find your other projects. List the sonatype shnapshot repo in each project file.

A repository manager only helps those with access to it. That is ok if the users are in one organisation. Using the sonatype repository reaches a wider circle.